# Minimum of two columns in a 3rd column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, min

**df**

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4    Col5
3       1      22     13      0
5       4      10      12     14
1       2      1        1      1

and so on
```

**Code**

```
df['Col6'] = df.min(axis=1)
```

This will return minimum of all 5 columns but **I want a column which returns minimum of 2 columns
Minimum of col 4 and col 1 lets say in a 6th column.** How can I get that

**Output expected**: Min of col1 and col4 rounded off to 2 decimal places

df[6] = round(min(df[col4], df[col1]),2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter both columns by list and then add [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['Col6'] = df[['Col4','Col1']].min(axis=1).round(2)
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
0     3     1    22    13     0     3
1     5     4    10    12    14     5
2     1     2     1     1     1     1
```

Your solution should working with [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round.html):

```
df['Col6'] = np.round(np.minimum(df['Col4'], df['Col1']),2)
```